# how to invite facebook friend in ios7?

Tags: iphone, ios7

am new in ios development

when i click "find your facebook friend" button then invitaion goes to this my salected friend

how can i code for this.am using facebook sdk framework.

```
NSLog(@"ID=%@",[_IDArray lastObject]);
NSLog(@"Event ID:%@",_eventID);


NSData *data = [_eventID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"Event ID:%@",[json objectForKey:@"id"]);

NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/invited/%@",[json objectForKey:@"id"],[_IDArray lastObject]]];
//@"https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3"
SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                    URL:meurl
                                             parameters:nil];

merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

[merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data=%@",meDataString);
}];
```

}
}

but i want to use facebook sdk
please help out

Comment: when i click button then invitation go to facebook friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook have shared the way to send request and invitation as:[Facebook tutorial friend requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial/#requests)